# Macro to select multiple sheets based on check boxes

Tags: excel, printing, vba

I need a macro that will, based on check boxes, select different sheets of my document. It's for print purposes. I have a list of check boxes, and a function to print each sheet who's box is checked.

My current macro basically works like this:

If (check box for sheet one) is check, then
select sheet one, then
print selected sheet

If (check box for sheet two) is check, then
select sheet two, then
print selected sheet

etc...

It runs like this through about 100 sheets. So it runs 100 separate print jobs. At my work you get a cover sheet for each job. So that's 100 cover sheets.

I'd like to have my macro just add workbooks to the WORKBOOK.SELECT function as it checks the check box, and then runs the print function once with all those selections. Any help?

PS- If someone has a solution that can be done in VBA, I'm open to that as well.

PPS- Someone asked to see the code. I'm new to stack exchange so this might be ugly....

So here is how it works:
Each checkbox has a cell in a sheet called 'prt_res' associated with it. You check the box for PR001, and the cell in the prt_res associated with the PR001 checkbox is set to TRUE. The this macro runs and looks for all the TRUEs:

```
Mprtsel
=IF(prt_res!B1=TRUE,GOTO(DF3),GOTO(DF5))
=WORKBOOK.SELECT("PR001","PR001")
=PRINT(1,,,1,FALSE,FALSE,1,,,600,600)
=IF(prt_res!B2=TRUE,GOTO(DF6),GOTO(DF8))
=WORKBOOK.SELECT("PR002","PR002")
=PRINT(1,,,1,FALSE,FALSE,1,,,600,600)
=IF(prt_res!B3=TRUE,GOTO(DF9),GOTO(DF11))
=WORKBOOK.SELECT("PR003","PR003")
=PRINT(1,,,1,FALSE,FALSE,1,,,600,600)
=IF(prt_res!B4=TRUE,GOTO(DF12),GOTO(DF14))
=WORKBOOK.SELECT("PR003A","PR003A")
=PRINT(1,,,1,FALSE,FALSE,1,,,600,600)
=IF(prt_res!B5=TRUE,GOTO(DF15),GOTO(DF17))
=WORKBOOK.SELECT("PR004","PR004")
=PRINT(1,,,1,FALSE,FALSE,1,,,600,600)
=IF(prt_res!B6=TRUE,GOTO(DF18),GOTO(DF20))
=WORKBOOK.SELECT("PR004A","PR004A")
=PRINT(1,,,1,FALSE,FALSE,1,,,600,600)
=IF(prt_res!B7=TRUE,GOTO(DF21),GOTO(DF23))
=WORKBOOK.SELECT("PR005","PR005")
=PRINT(1,,,1,FALSE,FALSE,1,,,600,600)
```

It runs like this for about 100 different sheets.

PPPS- Also, I know this is a terrible setup. I didn't write this. I just inherited it.

EDIT:

Okay! I have written a little VBA function that does what I need it to do, and gives me a nice little variable containing the value that I need to plug into the workbook.select function. This is it:

```
Public Function sConcat() As Variant
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim r As Integer

    For c = 2 To 6 Step 2
        For r = 1 To 46
            If Cells(r, c) = True Then
                sConcat = sConcat & Cells(r, c - 1) & ","
            End If
        Next r
    Next c
    sConcat = Left(sConcat, Len(sConcat) - 1)
End Function
```

The output of this function is the list of selected sheet names, comma separated. Like this

"PR001","PR003","PR301"

Now I don't know how to get that value into my excel macro. I'm thinking maybe something like:

```
WORKBOOK.SELECT({sConcat()})
```

but I know that isn't it. So How do I access this value in my macro. Google isn't being very helpful.

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing an edit to the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this after selecting all of the worksheets to print?

```
 ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1
```

Comment: The issue is that I don't have the worksheets selected. I'm checking boxes associated with the worksheets. I need to figure out how to select the sheets based on the checked boxes associated with each sheet.

Comment: That is a very messy way of doing things. I'd recommend that you build a user form to display the checkboxes, then cycle through the checked items, selecting them, then doing the print in the manner I discussed. Since there doesn't seem to a coorelation between the Checkbox and sheet name, it will be hard to go about this without making a number of changes. Maybe starting with something [like this](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/insert-checkboxes-in-excel-2010/) to create a proxy value with the sheet name for each checkbox, and work from there.